# android-No properties to serialize found on class

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database

i'm using realtime database (firebase) in my app,and when i try to insert value i have the

> "No properties to serialize found on class"

i tried all the answer found in stackoverflow, changing proguard-rules, making everything public, putting getters and putting @keep before the class
here is my proguard-rules

```js
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /Users/apple/Softwares/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
# Add this global rule
-keepattributes Signature

# This rule will properly ProGuard all the model classes in
# the package com.yourcompany.models. Modify to fit the structure
# of your app.

-keep class  com.android.pfe.other.**{ *; }

#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

and here is my user class, the error comes from
"mDatabase.child(UserId).setValue(user);"

```
    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(com.android.pfe.other.User.class)
    }
    @IgnoreExtraProperties
   @Keep
   public class User implements Serializable {
    public String username;
    public String email;
    public List contact;
    public List article;
    public DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void addUser(String UserId, String name, String email) {
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
        User user = new User(name, email);
        mDatabase.child(UserId).setValue(user);
    }}
```

here is where i call it

```
mEnregistrer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         final String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = mMdp.getText().toString().trim();
         final String pseudo =mPseudo.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pseudo)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entrer le pseudo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entrer une adresse mail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entrer un mot de passe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (password.length() < 6) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mot de passe trop court, veuillez rentrer un minimum de 6 caractères", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }


        //création compte
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(SignupActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Inscription réussie " + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            //changer les infos utilisateur
                            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setDisplayName(pseudo)
                                    .build();

                            user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Log.d(TAG, "com.android.pfe.other.User profile updated.");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                          //the part that bug
                            User uti=new User(pseudo,email);
                            uti.addUser(user.getUid(),pseudo,email);
                            startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                            finish();
                       //*****************************************************
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "erreur d'inscription" + task.getException().getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                    }
                });
    }   
});
```

Comment: the error was when calling the constructor `User(String,String)` in the `signupActivity` and calling it again in the `AddUser` method from the `User.class` ,delete the first constructor